# Remove indices from array and compact

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a card game for school and i am trying to implement a method to delete cards at specified indices, then compact the array..

This is the code I have so far (nonworking) - can anyone give me some pointers as to where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
private boolean removeCardsAt(int[] index){
    cards[index] = cards[cards.length - 1];
    Card[] newCards = new Card[cards.length - 1];
    for( int i = 0; i < newCards.length; i++) {
        newCards[i] = cards[i];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Should `index` be of type `int` (now `int[]`)?

Comment: Nothing about this makes sense. Pointers aren't going to help much.

Comment: I'm assuming she's parsing in multiple indices for removal, eg cards 3, 4, 5. @Zefick. To answer your question OP , It is hard to tell without seeing some sort of implementation code. Could you include this / expected outcomes ?

Comment: Cards at specified indices and compact the array.
if any indices do not correspond to cards then the array must be unchanged and this member returns false otherwise the specified cards are deleted, the array compacted and true returned.
-param index index of array element to delete
-return true if all elements successfully deleted, false if none deleted.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a type problem at `cards[index]`: this doesn't make sense, as `index` is an array. Perhaps you want to loop over the elements of `index`?
2. You have a loop to copy elements from one array to the other. However, you `return true` inside the loop. That means that your loop will only run for one iteration.
3. Your code doesn't actually compact the array or eliminate cards at the given indices. It's not really close yet, either. Here's a hint (since this is homework): right now, you're copying elements from one array to the other while keeping indices the same. What if you made the index into the old array differ by an offset from the index into the new array under certain circumstances?

You might want to try writing this assuming that there's only one card to eliminate, then generalize it to multiple cards.

Answer (score 0):

Considering paramter paased is array of indecis to be removed from Cards array:-

```
private static boolean removeCardsAtIndex(int[] index){
        int cardsLength = cards.length;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < index.length ; i++){
            int paramInt = index[i];
            int numberOfElements = cards.length - paramInt - 1;
            if (numberOfElements > 0) {
                  System.arraycopy(cards, paramInt + 1, cards, paramInt, numberOfElements);
                  cards[(--cardsLength)] = null;
            }
        }
        Card[] newCards = new Card[cardsLength];
        for( int i = 0; i < cardsLength; i++) {
            newCards[i] = cards[i];

        }
        if(newCards.length < cards.length){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Note:** After each iteration on index array,Copy the elements after the index,onto the same array starting at index position,Also card elements indexes are updated on each iteration.